# Prove that there is a differential equation whose flow is $\phi$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, vector-fields

Suppose that $\phi$ is a smooth flow, i.e., $\phi(0,x)=x$ and $\phi(t+s,x)=\phi(t,\phi(s,x))$. I want to prove that there is a
differential equation whose flow is $\phi$.
Moreover, is that possible that two different differential equations have the same flow?

Comment: To define a differential equation you need to define a way to assign a tangent vector to each point $x$. Can you think of one, having a smooth flow $\varphi(t, x)$?

Comment: Please note that here $x$ is the initial condition. I think we can define $g (t,x):= \frac{\partial \phi (t,x)}{\partial t} $ which gives the tangent vector to the flow. However, we need to have a function $f$ s.t. $g (t,x)= f(\phi (t,x)) $. If $f$, $\phi$, and $g$ are invertible (I am not sure if that is the case), we can say $g^{-1}=\phi^{-1}(f^{-1}(t,x))$ and then $f=g(\phi^{-1}(t,x))$. Now the ODE will be $\dot{x}=f(x)$.

Comment: Quite close! But you have some sort of redundant information in $g(t, x)$: for example, $g(t+s, x) \equiv g(t, \phi(s, x))$. We can reduce this information in the following way. Note that there is a basic fact for a flow that given any point $x_0$ there is only one trajectory of the flow that passes through $x_0$. Since the flow is smooth, you can take derivatives. Let's assign to any point $x_0$ a tangent vector $\frac{\partial \phi(t, x)}{\partial t}(0, x_0)$. Thus we have defined a vector field $\mathcal{F}(x)$ and trajectories of flow $\phi$ are solutions of $\dot{x} = \mathcal{F}(x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Evgeny. You are right. Is there any other way to get an explicit form for the vector field (maybe in terms of the inverse of the function $\phi$ and $g$). Moreover, as you said, as long as the flow $\phi$ is smooth, its tangent vector is unique. Thus, the ODE corresponding to this flow is always unique, and the only requirement is the smoothness of the flow.